Failed to start slurmd service slurmd: error: Thread count (32) not multiple of core count (24)
When trying to set up a slurm node it shows the error: Thread count (32) not multiple of core count (24)
The CPU is a i9-13900ks, the information that displays lscpu is:
Architecture:            x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
Model name:            13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900KS
CPU family:          6
Model:               183
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  24
Socket(s):           1
Stepping:            1
I tried to set up slurm.config with the parameters that lscpu displays and all the combinations, and can't get it to start properly
COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=aries NodeAddr=localhost CPUs=32 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=24 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=192000 Gres=gpu:1,mps:100 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=system Nodes=aries Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
error: NodeNames=aries CPUs=32 match no Sockets, SocketsCoresPerSocket or SocketsCoresPerSocket*ThreadsPerCore. Resetting CPUs.
slurmd: error: Thread count (32) not multiple of core count (24)


I tried to set up slurm.config with the parameters that lscpu displays and all the combinations, and can't get it to start properly

What you can do is run slurmd -C on the compute nodes, it will output the line that you can directly include in the slurm.conf file and will correspond exactly to what Slurm is expecting.
